# ¿Por qué se me genera un scroll cuando se realiza una animación en css?

Tags: css, css3

Estoy animando solo un parrafo  con la liberia "Animate.css", el problema ocurre cuando ingresas a la página, veras que la animación del título se genera y ocasiona un scroll.

He tratado de evitarlo usando "overflow hidden", pero no he tenido éxito, me gustaría que me puedan orientar en donde esta el error que estoy cometiendo.

También les comento que estoy usando un "IntersectionObserver" en javascript para que se dispare la animación cuando el elemento se muestre en pantalla.

Estuve verificando si el error era en el javascript, pero veo que todo esta bien.

También les voy a dejar el código para que puedan revisarlo y orientarme.

Por útlimo les voy a dejar por aquí abajo el link de la página ya publicado en github pages para que puedan ver el problema que tengo, solo deben recargar la página y verán el problema con el que sigo batallando.

[Pagina Web para que puedan ver el problema](https://aprendizajedigital.github.io/cursos/cocina-peruana-ceviches-y-mariscos/inicio3.html)

```js
        const variable = document.querySelector(".c-header__title");
// variable.style.setProperty('--animate-duration', '10s');

const verificarVisibilidad = (entries) => { //devuelve una lista, por eso se usa el foreach, no importa que sea uno
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
        if(entry.isIntersecting){
            entry.target.classList.add("animate__animated");
            entry.target.classList.add("animate__zoomIn");
        }
        else{
            // entry.target.classList.remove("animate__zoomIn")
            // entry.target.classList.add("c-header__title--visible")
        }
    })
}

const observador = new IntersectionObserver(verificarVisibilidad, {
    root: null,
    rootMargin: "0px 0px 0px 0px",
    threshold: 1.0
});

if(variable !== null) observador.observe(variable); //Esta es una entrada
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap");

body{
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
}

.c-header {
  background-image: linear-gradient(RGBA(243, 62, 103, 1) 0 55%, RGBA(243, 62, 103, 0) 65% 100%);
  padding: 85px 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden; }
  .c-header__container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden; }
  .c-header__title {
    font-weight: 900;
    text-shadow: RGB(0 0 0/30%) 2px 0px 2px;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: white; }
  .c-header__title-span {
    color: RGB(255, 255, 0); }
  .c-header__subtitle {
    font-weight: 700;
    text-shadow: RGB(0 0 0/30%) 2px 0px 2px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: black;
    line-height: 1.5; }
  .c-header__subtitle-span {
    color: RGB(255, 0, 0); }
  .c-header__paragraph {
    font-weight: 800;
    text-shadow: RGB(0 0 0/30%) 2px 0px 2px;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white; }
  .c-header__container-video {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; }
  .c-header__video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 5px solid white;
    box-shadow: 5px 10px 30px #000000; }
```

```html
<body>
    <header class="c-header">
        <div class="c-header__container o-breakpoint">
            <p class="c-header__title js-header__title">COMIENZA TU <span class="c-header__title-span">PROPIO NEGOCIO</span> FLORAL SIN ALTAS INVERSIONES DE DINERO Y DOMINA LAS TÉCNICAS FLORALES SIN NECESIDAD DE SER <span class="c-header__title-span">UNA EXPERTA</span></p>
            <p class="c-header__subtitle">
                <mark>
                    <span class="c-header__subtitle-span">ADVERTENCIA ️:</span> ¡Estas a un paso de descubrir el método innovador que te permitirá <span class="c-header__subtitle-span">GENERAR INGRESOS</span> <br>
                    creando <span class="c-header__subtitle-span">LUJOSOS ARREGLOS FLORALES</span> , y eso no es todo ,<br>también te permitirá emprender un negocio rentable de alta demanda !
                </mark>
            </p>
            <p class="c-header__paragraph">Mira el Video Hasta el Final</p>
            <div class="c-header__container-video">
                <iframe class="c-header__video"
                        src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/706660059?h=757d719681&portrait=0&byline=0&title=0"
                        frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
```

Comment: la solucion es que debes definir bien el width del elemento que estes animando no puede ser una medida relativa como por ejemplo width = 100% porque genera ese scroll cuando se reinidia la animacion ... no se si es lo que solucione tu problema, pero tuve un error de ese tipo y descubri eso